# Small python quirk: Finding the index of first and last number within boundaries in a list

Tags: list, python-2.7, indexing

I have encountered a small annoying problem. My problem is this:

I have a series of number between 0 and 1:
   [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9]

and two boundaries, say 0.25 and 0.75.

I need a quick and pretty way to find the index of the first number and last number in the series, that are within the boundaries, in this case (2, 6)

I have so far only come up with a clumsy way using for loops and the break command.

thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Let's see your version. How else will we be able to tell you if it's good / if we have a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your series of numbers is always sorted, you can use [the `bisect` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) to perform [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search) for the endpoints:

```
>>> a = [.1, .2, .3, .4, .5, .6, .7, .8, .9]
>>> import bisect
>>> bisect.bisect_left(a, 0.25)
2
>>> bisect.bisect_right(a, 0.75) - 1
6
```

`bisect_left(a, x)` returns the position `p` such that every element of `a[:p]` is less than `x`, and every element of `a[p:]` is greater than or equal to `x`; this is exactly what you want for the lower bound.

`bisect_right` returns the position `p` such that every element of `a[:p]` is less than or equal to `x`, and `a[p:]` are all greater than `x`. So for the right bound, you need to subtract one to get the largest position `<= x`.

Comment: I haven't tested it, but it's possible that passing the result of the first bisect to the second as a `lo` parameter may be useful: `bisect_left(a, 0.75, 2)` for instance

Comment: @JonClements True, that should save a little bit of work in the second bisect call.

Comment: Well, on that size list I doubt it - where it's much larger and the lower bound is heavily towards the end, I'd imagine it would... but just thought I'd mention it :)

Comment: Well, it can't hurt. :)  But yeah, since binary search is O(lg n) it's only going to make any difference if the lower-bound-to-end array is an order of magnitude smaller than the original array. (Modulo cache-efficiency concerns, which probably doesn't matter since python lists are arrays of pointers anyway.)

Comment: Thanks for the swift response! This is exactly what I was looking for. I assume this approach is quite efficient as well?

Answer (score 3):

if you can use numpy:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9])
max_b = .75
min_b = .25
wh = np.where((data < max_b)*(data > min_b))[0]
left, right =  wh[0], wh[-1] + 1
```

or simply (thanks to dougal):

```
left, right = np.searchsorted(data, [min_b, max_b])
```

if you can't:

```
import bisect

data = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9]
max_b = .75
min_b = .25
left = bisect.bisect_left(data, min_b)
right = bisect.bisect_right(data, max_b)
```

plus or minus 1 on the right depending on if you want `data[right]` to be in the set, or `data[left:right]` to give you the set.

Comment: If you're using numpy, might as well use [`searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) (basically the same thing as bisect).

Comment: nifty, didn't know that function existed

Comment: I'm just using a list right now, but this might certainly come in handy later!